# How to combine geolocation and multiple markers using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I'm trying to create a map that is able to track my location and at the same time be able to display multiple markers. Am I able to combine the 2 JavaScript below? If not any idea on how I should do it?

**JavaScript for multiple markers**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var locations = [
  ['Hougang', 1.37265, 103.893658],
  ['Punggol', 1.400617, 103.907833],
  ['MacRitchie Reservoir', 1.346002, 103.825436],
  ['Bishan', 1.352051, 103.849125],
  ['Sentosa', 1.251226, 103.830757]
];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 15,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(1.37265, 103.893658),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
          map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
          return function () {
              infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
      })(marker, i));
  }
```

**JavaScript for current location**

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to combine the two. When you initialize the map and after plotting the Hougang... locations you can add the geolocation code. I wrote a demo that will show a smaller green icon for the geolocation. If the browser doesn't support geocoding nothing will appear, no errors will show either.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/7/

Keep in mind the geolocation does not work (for me at least) if the code is loaded locally from the hard drive. It must be served publicly.

```
// Check if user support geo-location
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var geolocpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: geolocpoint,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        }
        // Place a marker
        var geolocation = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: geolocpoint,
            map: map,
            title: 'Your geolocation',
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png'
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Maby a little late, but to run it on your local you can insert your api key within the api call : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&sensor=false

Answer (score 3):

The below is a working sample and its being used in my project

```
function AddInfoWidnow(marker,message)
{
     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: message });

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

     infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);

    }); 

}


function ShowOnMap(ContainerId, mapItems) {

var DefaultLatLng= new google.maps.LatLng('12.967461', '79.941824');

var mapOptions = {
    center: DefaultLatLng,
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    marker: true
};

var mapCust = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(ContainerId), mapOptions);

var arrJsonObject = JSON.parse(mapItems);

for (var y = 1; y <= arrJsonObject.length; y++) 
{

    var myLatLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(arrJsonObject[y - 1].Latitude, arrJsonObject[y - 1].Lonngitude);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng1,
    map: mapCust,
    title: 'Marked at '+ arrJsonObject[y - 1].markedDate
});

    addInfoWindows(marker,y-1,arrJsonObject);


    marker.setMap(mapCust);

}
}
```

use the below Json string to call it.

```
  var mapItems='[
  {
    "Latitude": "22.575897",
    "Lonngitude": "88.431754",
    "CustomerCode": "*$$$*",
    "CustomerName": "*@@@*",
    "markedDate": "2/20/2014 12:04:41 PM"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "22.615067",
    "Lonngitude": "88.431759",
    "CustomerCode": "*$$$*",
    "CustomerName": "*@@@*",
    "markedDate": "2/20/2014 3:02:19 PM"
  }
]';
    ShowOnMap(containerId2, mapItems);
```