# Combine Geolocation and markers using Google Maps Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create a map that shows your current locations and show markers in the city. So you can see if you are nearby a marker.

I have to codes at this time, and I need to combine them. But when i do that, the codes doesn't work anymore. Does somebody know how to combine those two JS? If not, is there a other way to do this?

**This is the JS for Geolocation:**

```
function initMap() 
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
zoom: 14,
});
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  var pos = {
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lng: position.coords.longitude
  };

  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
  map.setCenter(pos);
}, function() {
  handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
});
} else {
// Browser doesn't support Geolocation
handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
}
}
function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                    'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                    'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
}
```

**And this is the JS code I have made for the markers:**

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
var map;
var currentPage = 'mapA';
var markers = [
['Thuis',52.2203713,6.90032999999994],
['Bommelstein',52.22254299999999,6.911623800000029],
['Saxion', 52.21976009999999,6.889364500000056],
['Kroeg', 52.2206085,6.896547300000066],
['t Gat', 52.2211657,6.895848999999998],
['studieruimte de Bul', 52.22101940903001,6.8924690438436755]
];
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    draggable: true,
    panControl: false,
    scrollwheel: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    streetViewControl: false,
    overviewMapControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.489031, 7.039671)
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);

setMarkers();}function setMarkers(){
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var post = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: post,
        map: map
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: markers[i][0]
    });

    infowindow.open(map,marker);
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to combine geolocation and multiple markers using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932496/how-to-combine-geolocation-and-multiple-markers-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I am actually working on the samething had the same problem until a few minutes ago. I simply start the geolocation condition to find the position before declaring an object of the map and it worked for me. here is my simple code similar to yours:

```
function initMap() {
   // Try HTML5 geolocation.
   if (navigator.geolocation) {
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
           var currentpos = {
               lat: position.coords.latitude,
               lng: position.coords.longitude
           };
           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
               center: currentpos,
               zoom: 14,
           });

           var contentString = 'I found you';
           var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: contentString
           });

           var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos,
                map: map,
                title: 'marker with infoWindow'
           });
           marker.addListener('click', function() {
               infowindow.open(map, marker);
          });
      }, function() {
           handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
}
function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                          'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                          'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
}
```

Best of luck